# What does "0" mean in the ATP Rankings?

Tags: tennis, ranking, atp

On the ATP Tour site, in the ranking column, I see a "0" for some players and some weeks. What does this mean?

I am trying to measure the strength of the field of Wimbledon over time, between 2003-2022. In particular, I am looking at [Nicholas Kiefer's ranking in 2007](https://www.atptour.com/en/players/nicolas-kiefer/k316/rankings-history), where he has a ranking before 2007-06-04 and after 2007-07-09, but zeros for three weeks:

[image: Nicolas Kiefer Ranking History]

Answer (score 2):

It seems to mean he wasn't listed that week.

[Here](https://www.atptour.com/en/rankings/singles?rankRange=1-5000&rankDate=2007-07-09) is the list for 2007-07-09, where he's ranked #413, and [here](https://www.atptour.com/en/rankings/singles?rankRange=1-5000&rankDate=2007-07-02) the list for 2007-07-02, where he doesn't appear. (BTW, it's easier to change the URL than to find the right week in the dropdown.)

*Why* he wasn't listed that week is another good question...

Comment: I think it's because he hadn't played a match for over a year; from Wikipedia: "Kiefer injured his wrist while playing at the 2006 French Open, and announced his return on 5 July 2007"

Comment: Ah... Well, it is a 52 week ranking system, so if the player is inactive for longer, it makes sense that they would fall out of the system. Thank you.